# JComboBox dropdown menu is breaking swing application when cross the parent dialog border

Tags: java, swing

I have a pretty complex swing UI and I've the issue that after clicking a JComboBox the dropdown appears but after that the swing renderer goes insane and does the mess on entire swing application and app restart is the only way to fix it.

So I have a swing Application that has a JDialog which contains among the other the JComboBox component with some items. There is no uncaught exceptions in the logs. I did a lot of debug of my code and it looks fine.

The only thing that affects the issue is the amount of items in the combobox, if combobox dropdown is inside the JDialog border it works fine and the issue could not be reproduced, if the bottom part of the dropdown goes outside of JDialog window bottom border the issue happens.

This is the test code the breaks the swing while I'm using Adopt Open JDK 11.0.10+9:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialog dlg = new JDialog();
    JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>();

    JPanel spChEastD2 = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane spChEastScrollD2 = new JScrollPane(spChEastD2);
    spChEastScrollD2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("aaa"));

    JPanel channelsD2 = new JPanel();
    channelsD2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Channels"));
    channelsD2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 110));
    channelsD2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 110));
    channelsD2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 110));
    channelsD2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(channelsD2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JPanel centerD2 = new JPanel();
    centerD2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerD2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    centerD2.add(channelsD2);
    channelsD2.add(spChEastScrollD2);
    spChEastD2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 10));
    for (int i = 13; i < 54; i++) {
        cb.addItem("" + i);
    }
    spChEastD2.add(cb);
    dlg.add(centerD2);
    dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dlg.pack();
    dlg.setVisible(true);
}
```

Result after opening the dropdown menu of the combobox:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... it works with JDK 20 for me. So is there any *exact* way this occurs or just as soon as you open the combobox?

Comment: Yes it breaks as soon as I open the combobox. I start the test application, the dialog window appears I click the button with down triangle on the right side of the combobox and it happens.

Comment: Also works fine for me using Windows 11 and JDK 11. Probably an OS issue. 1) I would get rid of all the set...Size(...) statements. if you need extra space on a panel then use an EmptyBorder. 2) Make sure the GUI is created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).